.patch_storage cleanup after patching event
Can someone explain the difference between these commands
./opatch util listorderedinactivepatches
./opatch util deleteinactivepatches

and this one
./opatch util cleanup

Do I need to run all of them to cleanup .patch_storage?  Thanks in advance.

You have to run only first two commands. opatch util cleanup does not do what you’d expect it to do
